# ggplot: customize the color of margins of dots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to customize the color of the margins of the dots of my ggplot. The color of the fill of dots summarize one information while 
the color of the margins will summarize another one.

Suppose to use the mtcars data:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl), shape = factor(vs)))
```

Then suppose you want to modify the color of the margin of dots using the column mtcars$carb.

Is it possible using `ggplot`?

Comment: Do you also need to map something to shape?

Comment: You need shapes that have a separate fill and border, like shapes 21:25.  So you could use `scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 22, 23) )` or something and then use `fill` for `carb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use  `fill` for the inside color and `color` for the line color. And you need to use shapes that differentiate between the two (that is, shapes 21-25. Search "r pch" or see the help page at `?pch` for all the shapes). Unfortunately, for the legends to look right, we need to manually specify shapes for the legends. You may also want to use at least one `manual` scale (e.g., `scale_fill_manual`) specifying your own colors so that the fill and line colors are more different.

```
ggplot(mtcars,
    aes(
      x = wt,
      y = mpg,
      color = factor(carb),
      fill = factor(cyl),
      shape = factor(vs)
    )) + geom_point(size = 2, stroke = 1.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21, 24)) +
  scale_fill_hue(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21))) +
  scale_color_hue(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)))
```

[image]
See also the example at the bottom of the `?geom_point` help page:

```
# For shapes that have a border (like 21), you can colour the inside and
# outside separately. Use the stroke aesthetic to modify the width of the
# border
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, colour = "black", fill = "white", size = 5, stroke = 5)
```

Comment: Do you know the reason why fill legend is all black?

Comment: I usually end up having to use `override.aes` to get a proper "filled" shape for the `fill` legend.

Comment: @Bnf8 Glad it helped. If you consider the issue solved, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the votes/score. This indicates you are not still looking for more answers (and gives us each a little reputation).